# Find the Green's function for $[(1+x)u']'+(\sin{x})u=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

I am trying to find the Green's function for the following ODE,
$$[(1+x)u']'+(\sin{x})u=0$$ with the boundary conditions $u(0)=u(1)=0$ and $x\in[0,1]$.

What I have done is tried to integrate the equation after simplifying (i.e differentiating the first term) and put the given conditions, but got stuck in mid way. How can I do this?

My work:
$$(1+x)u''+u'+(\sin{x})u=0$$
$$\int_{0}^{x}(1+x)u''dx+u(x)-u(0)+\int_{0}^{x}\sin{x}~u~dx=0$$
$$(1+x)u'(x)-u'(0)+u(x)+\int_{0}^{x}\sin{x}~u~dx=0$$ (using integration by parts and $u(0)=0$). Repeating the same step again for last equality I couldn't simplify it to find a neat result.

Second thought: If I can find solution to this ODE $$u''+\dfrac{1}{1+x}u'+\dfrac{\sin{x}}{1+x}u=0$$

Comment: Please show what you actually did. It will be easier to help...

Comment: Please help me. Any hint will also be good for me. I am new to this Green's function business.

Comment: Anybody please give me a hint. @mickep can u?

Comment: I don't see how it should be done here, sorry. Is this an exercise, or where did you find the problem?

Comment: This is an entrance exam problem. they ask to find the Green's function and check whether it is continuous at a specific point and so. It is really unsolvable?